# Displaying a table with textbox in J2ME?

Tags: java, java-me

How should we do the below the scenarios in J2ME?

Display the table. Inside the table, the cells need to be textboxes. The cells can have any value. The user should be able to edit it. If a user selects a cell then she should be able to edit it; the cell should shrink and enlarge based on the value, like in [Excel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be acheived by using the CutomItem (javax.microedition.lcdui.CustomItem).For editing the cell use the paint method and keyPressed() methods.